# UI Design Query : Many to many relationships for data entry UI

Tags: wpf, user-interface, data-entry

I am designing a Data Entry UI for a WPF application and have a scenario where I need to enter a many-many relationship.

Object A is Parent object. A has an observable collection of type Object B.

Object B has two text fields and an observable collection of Object C which has four text fields.

I need to create a UI which will allow an efficient addition of B and C.

I have created a Nested Tab Control where the outer tab control has object B and it has an inner tab control which can accommodate many object C in it.

However this UI looks ugly and non intuitive. Any suggestions on what would be a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a grid in master-detail(-detail) mode?

Check [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/monikadyrda/archive/2009/03/13/master-detail-patter-implemented-using-wpf.aspx) or [this](http://blogs.telerik.com/blogs/posts/09-01-16/master_detail_with_radgridview_for_wpf_using_objectdataprovider_and_ado_net_entities.aspx) or [this](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/DataGridWPF/) to bring you some ideas. Third party vendors like DevExpress and Telerik provide real good data grids and other user controls. Don't know if standard Microsoft DataGrid provides master-detail functionality. But this should give you some ideas.

Comment: you mean to say an editable datagrid where the user can add rows to both the master and detail grids? Will that be user friendly? I have observed that many users are not comfortable with entering data in datagrids.

Comment: Can be. It were just some ideas. And if you look at the other examples there's also a approach of using stack panels. When selecting an object in one stackpanel the child objects of the selected object are shown in another stackpanel and so on...And if you use DevExpress Grid -> they are very user-friendly and highly customizable to fit your user requirements.

Comment: Thanks Joep I settled for a Master Details view where one is a grid and another is a tab control!!

Comment: Hi Joep I marked the answer for this and many posts back.. sorry